Is it possible to improve orientation detection with tesseract by specifying language and script?
I am using tesseract to detect orientation of scanned images. They mostly contains text.
It works in general but sometimes fails, even for simple cases :



Input
Result





orientation: 0script: 'Cyrillic'



orientation: 180 script: 'Cyrillic'



I know the text is always 'Latin' and 'French/English'.
Is there a way to specify that to tesseract ? I found that it's possible to specify it while converting image to text (using image_to_string()) but not when detecting orientation.
Here is the code I use:
import pytesseract
import cv2

img = cv2.imread("somefile.jpg")    
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) #black and white
img = cv2.threshold(img, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1] #contrast
results = pytesseract.image_to_osd(img, output_type=pytesseract.Output.DICT)    
print(results["rotate"]) 


if I resample second image (using ImageMagick convert -resample 300 input.png output.png) then it recognize it as Latin and orientation 180. So your images may need to resampling to better resolution. You may use pillow or wand to resample it.

tesseract doc: Improving the quality of the output | tessdoc

BTW: I tested directly with tesseract in system: tesseract input.png - --psm 0. I tried to add option -l eng and it says it tests orietation only with -l eng

I tried to test it with easyocr -f input.png -l en but I don't have GPU and it doesn't work on my computer. Python module EasyOCR

I have tried to resize it with opencv but it does get any better : img = cv2.resize(img, (0, 0), fx = 2.0, fy = 2.0, interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC)

maybe it needs more work in CV - e.g Erosion and Dilatation, blurring and sharpening.

BTW: I tested second image 4 times bigger. width 146 -> 608.
